# Adding p:column programatically with filterBy and sortBy attributes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to create datatable column pragmatically ,using primeface 5.2 ,wildfly ,Mojarra 2.2.6

I have inherited from DataTable, and creating my own Columns,**i want to set  the sortBy,filterBy attributes using value expressions**  using the below code

```
public void AddCoulumn(String colName, String dbFieldName,
        boolean Searchable) {
    ValueExpression valExpr = null;
    Column column = new Column();
    valExpr = createValueExpression("#{obj." + dbFieldName + "}");
    column.setValueExpression("filterBy", valExpr);
    column.setValueExpression("sortBy", valExpr);
    column.setWidth("100px");
    column.setHeaderText(colName);
    HtmlOutputText out = new HtmlOutputText();
    out.setValueExpression("value", valExpr);
    out.setStyle("color:red");
    column.setField(dbFieldName);
    this.getChildren().add(column);

}
```

Unfortunately when trying to filter  results nothing occur and where trying to sort using any column i got this exception

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumnInGroup(DataTable.java:905) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:896) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.decode(SortFeature.java:86) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:62) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]**

thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for your attention i updated my question
your kindly support is highly appreciated

Comment: does it work without the filterBy and sortBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem after debugging the PrimeFaces datatable.
I found that if you try to sort or filter using specific column 
the datatable calls a findcolumn function which take string client id as a paramter: `findcolumn(string client id)`. Inside this function a function called `getcolumns()` retrieves the table columns... If the client id is found in the list it returns the column but in this case it never finds a column because PrimeFaces/JSF changes the columns id on the postback since the whole view is restored. So the column will not be found anymore

To solve this problem explicitly set the column id

```
column.setId(colName);
```

It works fine now